# How to get revision number from Mercurial repository and paste it to NetBeans resource bundle?

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, versioning, resourcebundle

I have a java project in NetBeans and im using Mercurial for version controlling.
I want to see my project version number in about box and i want it to be updated according to Mercurial revision number.
Any ideas how to do it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following '[Version numbering for auto builds with Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212435/version-numbering-for-auto-builds-with-mercurial)', you can record in a VERSION.TXT file (that you about dialog would display) the result of:

```
hg log -r . --template '{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}'
```

[Lazy Badger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960558/lazy-badger)  [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232469/how-to-get-revision-number-from-mercurial-repository-and-paste-it-to-netbeans-re/13232550#comment18026914_13232550):

> log will be a lot better (and correct) with:

```
hg log -r tip --template "{latesttag}.{latesttagdistance}"
```

You have more options in "[How good is my method of embedding version numbers into my application using Mercurial hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666674/6309)"

`version_gen.sh` with:

```
 hg parent --template "r{node|short}_{date|shortdate}" > version.num
```

> In the makefile, make sure `version_gen.sh` is run before `version.num` is used to set the version parameter.

Comment: Example of a `version_gen.sh` script: https://bitbucket.org/artbugorski/postmed/src/tip/util/version_gen.sh

Comment: log will be a lot better (and correct) with `hg log -r tip --template "{latesttag}.{latesttagdistance}"`

Comment: @LazyBadger ok, I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have a need to get this (programmatically) from a given branch, so I used `hg log -l 1 -b <branchname> --template "{node}\n"`

Answer (score 0):

If Windows, [MercurialRev](https://bitbucket.org/JPlenert/mercurialrev) ("SubWCRev for Mercurial") may be useful also

```
Replaces revision information in a tagged text file.

MercurialRev <SourceFile> <DestinationFile> <RepositoryPath>

Tags:
    <$HG:REV_NUM$>
    <$HG:REV_LMOD_N$>
    <$HG:REV_LMOD_P$>
    <$HG:REV_ID$>
    <$HG:BRANCH$>
    <$HG:TAG$>
```